# As a Interviewer, how do I keep track of Interview impressions?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, productivity

I'm a technical Lead in a small organization, and I provide technical inputs to HR in the recruitment process. My involvement in the recruitment process is limited to the following:

1. Creating the Job Description and passing that to HR
2. Filtering the CVs after HR has filtered them.
3. Conducting an Initial Telephonic interview.
4. Being in the Interview Panel in the Face to Face on site interview.

HR has a template for steps 3 & 4 which I fill up and submit. But I'm feeling that this does not meet my needs, in tracking the CVs, specially in the following cases:

- HR might accidentally pass on the same CV for a different position.
- I might feel that I person I had earlier interviewed on the phone and rejected for one position might now be suitable for different position.

My attempt at solving this issue, is to record as much information as I can in an Excel Sheet, but I'm finding that unwieldy and end up not filling it half the time.

I'm *not asking for software recommendations*. I'm asking if there are any tricks or procedures that you follow, which would help in recording this kind of non structured information. While conducting an interview, one notices a lot of things, and very little of that is actually recorded, and formally filled. What about all these other things that come to mind of an interviewer? What do you do with them? How do you make sure that they are useful in the future?

Comment: Hey Devdatta, and welcome to the Workplace. I have a feeling this will be considered off-topic, though I am not voting to close necessarily. For everyone considering closing, please at the very minimum [read this meta question first](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/) since it is very relevant. You may want to read it too Devdatta, and see if you can't [edit] your answer to make it less likely to be closed!

Comment: @jmac: I wasn't requesting a software recommendation, but I can see how my question could be interpreted that way. I have edited my question to better clarify my question. I hope it is clear enough, but if it's not, do leave a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Devdatta, I'm not trying to be critical at all -- I think it's an interesting question, I just don't know if the community thinks this is the right place for it. On one hand it sounded like a software recommendation, but on the other hand people may see it as "how do I do my job?" which is also off-topic. Hopefully one of our resident HR experts has a good answer that will give so much value to the question that people can't resist but upvote the question that inspired it!

Answer (score 5):

> I'm asking if there are any tricks or procedures that you follow

Whenever I review a resume/CV, I write down some notes. In situations where the resume/CV is printed, I simply attach those notes and file them for future reference. In situations where the resume/CV is not printed, I simply write those notes in a Word document, and file them appropriately.

When I conduct a phone interview, I first create a template of the questions I intend to ask of every client, leaving plenty of time and room for other questions that may arise. I scribble some notes down while I'm on the phone, then write them up immediately after the phone interview and file them appropriately.

When I conduct an in-person interview, create a similar template. During the in-person interview I scribble far fewer notes (since it's more important to listen during the interview). I spend more time writing up my notes immediately after the interview, then I file them appropriately.

Whenever HR or others ask for follow-up for a candidate, I have my notes at the ready.

Over the many years I've been part of the interviewing process, this has served me well.

Comment: If you're getting the CVs in PDF form, you can use the markup tools built into Adobe Reader (others as well, I'm sure; MS Word has a similar feature built in for its documents) to put your notes right on the document itself. This will save you from having to manage two separate files.

Comment: This is roughly what I do.  I write directly on the printout of the resume (I always print it), and similarly I write directly on my page of questions/topics.  I may *also* write up a formal summary (for actual interviews it's required by HR), but I keep those original notes.

Comment: In addition to this, if I feel that the candidate isn't a good fit for my position but might be a good fit for another position, I tell that to HR.  Even if there isn't a position currently open, HR might know that there is a position soon to be open, or that a position could be opened if the right candidate were to arrive.  If I think that the candidate would be a good candidate for a specific manager, I CC that manager on my mail to HR so that they can follow up with HR about the candidate.

Comment: Paper is a thing. It’s amazing how few people use paper anymore!